# Ansible: how to remove AWS IAM group with an inline policy defined? (Ansible claims "changed" without performing the action)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

When AWS IAM group has an inline policy defined, the following Ansible task does not remove the group, although task status claims "changed":

```
- name: Ensure group {{ group_name }} exists
  iam:
    iam_type: group
    name: "{{ group_name }}"
    state: absent
```

The `iam` module doc page contains a [note](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/iam_policy_module.html#notes):

> Currently boto does not support the removal of Managed Policies, the module will not work removing/adding managed policies.

but this is an [inline policy, not a managed one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html).

As a workaround, because the return JSON contains `delete_group` key, I can at least cause the task to fail by adding:

```
  register: deletion_result
  failed_when: not deletion_result.delete_group
```

But why does it claim "changed" when the action was not performed (and it knows that, because `delete_group` is set to either true or false)?

Is it a bug in Ansible, or am I missing something?

And the big question: how to remove the group with a defined inline policy using Ansible?

---

**MCVE**

- My play (create group, assign policy, delete group, delete group - again to show the problem):

  ```
  ---
  - hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: no

    vars:
      group_name: test_group_01
      policy_name: test_policy_01

    tasks:
      - name: Ensure group {{ group_name }} exists
        iam:
          iam_type: group
          name: "{{ group_name }}"
          state: present

      - name: Ensure policy {{ policy_name }} exists and is assigned to group {{ group_name }}
        iam_policy:
          iam_type: group
          iam_name: "{{ group_name }}"
          policy_name: "{{ policy_name }}"
          policy_document: ./policy.j2
          state: present

      - name: Ensure group {{ group_name }} does not exist
        iam:
          iam_type: group
          name: "{{ group_name }}"
          state: absent

      - name: Ensure group {{ group_name }} does not exist
        iam:
          iam_type: group
          name: "{{ group_name }}"
          state: absent
  ```

  `policy.json` (not relevant for results, just for completeness):

  ```
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "Stmt2017010101",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "s3:ListBucket"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
  ```
- The actual result:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

  TASK [Ensure group test_group_01 exists] ***************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [Ensure policy test_policy_01 exists and is assigned to group test_group_01] ***
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [Ensure group test_group_01 does not exist] *******************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [Ensure group test_group_01 does not exist] *******************************
  changed: [localhost]

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=4    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
  ```
- Expected result:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

  TASK [Ensure group test_group_01 exists] ***************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [Ensure policy test_policy_01 exists and is assigned to group test_group_01] ***
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [Ensure group test_group_01 does not exist] *******************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [Ensure group test_group_01 does not exist] *******************************
  ok: [localhost]

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the `iam` module.

[Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/iam.py#L455) (and in some other places) error message is tested against string *'must detach all policies first'*, but as of today the actual error message is *'Cannot delete entity, must delete policies first.'*.

You can replace all *'must detach all policies first'* to *'must delete policies first'* in `iam.py` and you will get expected behaviour of the module.

Comment: P.S. I'm a bit lazy on this day after New Year to file an issue and PR to ansible repo.